# How to use IDatabaseConnectionInfo3 Interface ArcObjects!

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, java

I try to retrive the connected users from an entreprise geodatabase using ArcObjects .

first I tried to cast My workspace to IDatabaseConnectionInfo3 but it throws

> ClassCastException

```
IWorkspace workspace = sdeWorkspaceInstance();
IDatabaseConnectionInfo3 databaeseConnectinfo = (IDatabaseConnectionInfo3) workspace;
IEnumUserInfo listUserInfo = databaeseConnectinfo.getConnectedUsers();
```

Any idea how to use the IDatabaseConnectionInfo3 interface ?

Comment: try IDatabaseConnectionInfo instead of IDatabaseConnectionInfo3. Make sure your sdeWorkspace is really sde and not e.g. FGDB

Comment: I dont need to use IDatabaseConnectionInfo 
because , what I need  is retriving a list of users not just the admin user

IDatabaseConnectionInfo has the getConnectedUser(); which return a "String" instead of getConnectedUsers();

Comment: what does IWorkspace.Type returns for your workspace? and Is your workspace an admin workspace?

Comment: what do you mean by "is your workspace an admin workspace ?
If you mean that I access my sde workspace by adminGDD user : yes 
I'm using an sde entreprise database . 
and I create the workspace using 

                        IWorkspaceFactory sdeFactory;
                        sdeFactory= new SdeWorkspaceFactory();
                        IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet();
   propertySet.setProperty("SERVER", "10.5.28.143");
                           all others info......
   propertySet.setProperty("VERSION", "SDE.DEFAULT");
   return (IWorkspace) pSdeFact.open(propertySet, 0);

Answer (score 2):

The [JavaDoc](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/datasourcesGDB/Sde4Workspace.html) does **not** state that `Sde4Workspace` implements `IDatabaseConnectionInfo3` -- It only asserts `IDatabaseConnectionInfo`, which is a superinterface.  Therefore the cast *should* fail (which it does).

If you want to ask Esri why the connection interface doesn't support server info queries, you would need to contact Tech Support, but I suspect it has to do with the difference between the underlying objects -- an Sde4Workspace is essentially a wrapper around `SE_CONNECTION` (from the 'C' API), while the list of connected users in an instance is a wrapper around `SE_instance_get_users` (which is a poll of the *now* *deprecated* application server).

You could certainly use an `Sde4Workspace` to fashion a SQL query of the connected users, though this would differ slightly by RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

An SDE workspace should implement that interface, unless it's an [Sde3Workspace](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/datasourcesGDB/Sde3Workspace.html) object. But to be honest, I don't know the difference between Sde3Workspace and [Sde4Workspace](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/datasourcesGDB/Sde4Workspace.html).

As with all ArcObjects enumerators, you need to call `Reset()` first, and then loop over the results using `Next()`. Note that `ConnectedUsers` may throw an exception if you do not have permission to see the connected users.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use the Java ArcObjects SDK, but I guess it should be very similar to C#, so here's an example:

```
private void GetConnectedUsers(IWorkspace workspace)
{
    var connectionInfo = workspace as IDatabaseConnectionInfo3;
    if (connectionInfo == null) return; // Other types of workspace, e.g. fgdb

    IEnumUserInfo listUserInfo;
    try
    {
        listUserInfo = connectionInfo.ConnectedUsers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // May not have permission to see connected users
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    listUserInfo.Reset();

    IUserInfo userInfo;
    while ((userInfo = listUserInfo.Next()) != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(userInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx ,

but really I dont understand I just wrote the same as described in your C# code. 

'code'var connectionInfo = workspace as IDatabaseConnectionInfo3;'code'
in java :
'IDatabaseConnectionInfo3 databaeseConnectinfo = (IDatabaseConnectionInfo3) worspace;'

and it throws the :'java.lang.ClassCastException: com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.Workspace cannot be cast to com.esri.arcgis.geodatabase.IDatabaseConnectionInfo3'

i'm so Confused !